# How to pass two parameter into webservice

Tags: swift, api, web-services

I have web service

```
http://dev.nsol.sg/projects/sneakers/Api/get_single_news
```

Method: POST
Required Parameters:

```
userid

newsid
```

Response:

```
success = 0 (error), 1 (success)
message = Description of result if success = 0 then message will have the detail description
data: if success = 1 then we will have complete details of common requirements like single news
newsurl: News Image URL + Concatenate Value of img from DB
```

Here is my try to fetch data from url

```
func single_news(userid: Int) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: news_url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        //Pass your parameter here
        let postString = "userid=\(userid)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=(error)")
                return
            }


            let json: Any?

            do
            {

                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print("abcnews")
                //here is your JSON
                print(json)
            }
            catch
            {
                return
            }

            guard let server_response = json as? NSDictionary else
            {
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

How to pass the second parameter newsid.You can download the project from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mBlYcNaW8K3s6Y2V6BY6zdM0Znvyw3Si/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your function

```
func single_news(userid: Int , newsid : Int) {}
```

I assume that `newsid` is also an `Int` value.

And write your `postString` like this...

```
let postString = "userid=\(userid)&newsid=\(newsid)"
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you just want to create and send a JSON object with two properties.

You can do it like this:

```
let body: [String: Any] = ["userid": userid, 
                           "newsid": newsid]

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
```